# Android: How do I intercept a touch event on a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, events, touch, intercept, dispatch

How do I intercept a touch event on a DialogFragment before it is dispatched to the dialog ?
When I want to intercept a touch event on an Activity I override dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) for that Activity. How can I do something similar for a DialogFragment?
It seems that dispatchTouchEvent has no effect for the fragments included in the Activity.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do more precisely?